# Install 15+ days old updates only

Tags: 16.04, updates

I want to install updates in my system if they've been submitted in repo for at least 2 weeks.

I know the settings in `software & update`, but they don't quite meet my requirements.

[image: software & updates settings]

Is there anyway to achieve something like this

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade where release_date < (Date.Now - 15 days)
```

Comment: Why do you want this feature?

Comment: @sudodus, I want to keep a buffer time so if there are any bugs on the freshly released updates, they'll get fixed. I know that's highly improbable, but still I'd like to know if there is an option.

Comment: If you stay with an LTS release, the updates will be extra carefully tested, and the risk is small. (I don't know if/how you can delay the updates 15 days, but let us hope that someone else can help you.)

Comment: Some updates are important security updates. Let the system update normally and if you get a buggy update roll it back. It's not hard to do it that way, and your system will be more secure.

Comment: @karel, thank you. linux mint introduced this feature in their software update manager, so there must be a way.